# Adding a pagenavi to function for displaying bookmarks

Tags: plugins, functions, pages, navigation

I have [a plugin user bookmarks - see here -](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/restrict-content/)  and I'm trying to add a  to it so the bookmark posts don't pile up like crazy. How can I do it? This is the function that displays the bookmarked posts.

```
function upb_list_bookmarks( $delete_link = true, $delete_text = 'Delete' ) {
if(is_user_logged_in()) {
    $display = '<ul class="upb-bookmarks-list" style="margin-left:0px;">';
        $bookmarks = upb_get_user_meta(upb_get_user_id());
        if($bookmarks) {
            foreach( $bookmarks as $bookmark) {
                $display .= '<li class="upb_bookmark bookmark-' . $bookmark . '" style="float: left; width: 200px; list-style-type: none; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom:22px; margin-right: 25px; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 35px; padding-left: 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat;" >';
                $display .= '<div class="sjena" style="display:inline-block; width:200px; height:200px; clear:both; margin-right:25px; margin-bottom:-33px;">';
                $display .= '<div class="item_lists_thumbnail" >';
                $display .= '<span class="thumbs for-image" >';
                $display .= '<a href="' . get_permalink($bookmark) . '">';
                    $display .= '<img style="width:200px; height:150px;" src="' . get_post_meta($bookmark, '_post_thumbnail', true) . '" alt=""  />';
                    $display .= '<span class="title">';
                    $display .= '<p>';                      
                    $display .=  limit_text(get_the_title($bookmark), 25);                     
                    $display .= '</p>';
                    $display .= '</span>';
                    $display .= '</a>'; 
                    $display .= '</span>';
                    $display .= '<div class="item_lists_meta" style="background:#FFF; height:190px;"></div>';
                    $display .= '<div id="bookmark_minus"></div>';
                        if($delete_link) {
                        $display .= '<a style="position:absolute; margin-top:-27px; margin-left:24px; font-family: Terminal Dosis; font-weight: 500; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:10px;" href="#" class="upb_del_bookmark upb_del_bookmark_' . $bookmark . '" rel="' . $bookmark . '" title="' . __('Remove this Bookmark') . '">' . 'remove' . '</a>' ;
                    }
                    $display .= '</div>';                       
                $display .= '</div>';
            $display .= '</li>';
            }
        } else {
            $display .= '<li class="bookmark-link no-bookmarks">You do not have any favorited looks :(</li>';
        }
    $display .= '</ul>';
}
else {
    $display .= 'You must be logged in to view your bookmarks.';
}

return $display;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to implement a simple an flexible paging mechanism using JavaScript/JQuery/Ajax or using PHP.

If looking for the client side solution, [this article about jQuery pagination plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/) might be a good starting point for your research.

If you want to make more than one one actual page, you should use PHP. You can introduce a custom query variable for your paging then. Maybe [this article](http://www.blackbam.at/blackbams-blog/2011/07/18/implementing-a-simple-and-flexible-paging-algorithm-using-php/) will help you with this.